# Area ratio of a minimum bounding rectangle of a convex polygon

Tags: convex-geometry, computational-geometry, geometry

Take a convex polygon $P$ in the plane, and find its minimum area bounding rectangle, $R$. I'm interested in the ratio of the area of $R$ to the area of $P$. The ratio has a minimum of $1$ for rectangles and is $2$ for triangles. I want to say that $2$ is the maximum ratio possible.

Is this known? Is there a nice proof/counterexample for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is easy to prove.  Assume you have at least four points and take the longest chord $C$ of the polygon.  Now choose your rectangle such that two edges are parallel and the same length as $C$.  Now observe that since each "half" of the polygon contains a triangle inscribed in the "half" rectangle (where "half" means cut by $C$), at least half of each side of the rectangle is filled.

Comment: the rest of the argument being that the minimum area bounding rectangle has area no bigger than the one that 
you specify.

Comment: Right, in other words that the rectangle actually contains the polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer: it is [a result of Dutkovsky](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5188175/rectangle.pdf) that the area of a rectangle containing a curve of *perimeter* $2\pi$ is at most $4.$

**EDIT** I have just learned (from Erwin Lutwak) that the result is *NOT* a result of Dutkovsky, but a result of Lutwak, as in:
Lutwak, E.
On isoperimetric inequalities related to a problem of Moser. 
Amer. Math. Monthly 86 (1979), no. 6, 476–477.